# Hidden dimension in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm

[image]

From https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html

Sequence length is 5 ,batch size is 1 and both dimensions are 3. So we have the input as 5x1x3 . If we are processing 1 element at a time , input is 1x1x3 [thats why we are taking i.view(1,1,-1). What I am confused about is how do i decide what the hidden dimension is. Why is it specified like

hidden = (torch.randn(1,1,3),torch.randn(1,1,3))

Doc says:
h_0 of shape (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size):
1x1x3 . But why is it concatenated with another 1x1x3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doc says: h_0 of shape (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size): 1x1x3 . But why is it concatenated with another 1x1x3 ?

LSTMs have two memory components, sometimes called the "cell state" and the "memory state".

Comment: Is there a good way in general to visualize 3d LSTM vectors?